# How do I loop through a list and remove an item in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to figure out how to remove an item from a list in groovy from within a loop.

```
static main(args) {
   def list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
   for(num in list1){
   if(num == 2)
      list1.remove(num)
   }
   println(list1)
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify. I know I don't need the loop, but this demonstrates what I'm trying to do without putting a bunch of extra logic in the example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to remove the item with *index* 2, you can do

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
list.remove(2)
assert list == [1,2,4]

// or with a loop
list = [1,2,3,4]
i = list.iterator()
2.times {
    i.next()
}
i.remove()
assert list == [1,2,4]
```

If you want to remove the (first) item with *value* 2, you can do

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
list.remove(list.indexOf(2))
assert list == [1,3,4]

// or with a loop
list = [1,2,3,4]
i = list.iterator()
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (i.next() == 2) {
        i.remove()
        break
    }
}
assert list == [1,3,4]
```

Comment: in reality, this does not really work. `i = my.object.here.iterator()` simply does not work

Comment: It works with lists.  It should work with any object that implements the `Iterable` interface or has an `iterator()` method.

Answer (score 21):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newList = list.findAll { it != 2 }
```

Should give you all but the 2

Of course you may have a reason for requiring the loop?

Comment: That doesn't explain Java's ConcurrentModificationException that the OP (original poster) had received (the most likely solution on that issue would be to use a CopyOnWriteArrayList in the Java world), but, in my eyes, this is the most practical way in Groovy. - Please, may, additionally, everyone note that the List.remove(int) method differs from the List.remove((Object) int) method.

Comment: In groovy it calls remove by index when you have a list of integers.

Answer (score 7):

As you state in your comment that you do not specifically require a loop .... If you are happy to modify your original list you can use `removeAll`:

```
// Remove all negative numbers
list = [1, 2, -4, 8]
list.removeAll { it < 0 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do:

```
list - 2;
```

or...

```
list.remove(2)
```

There's no loop required.

If you want to use a loop I guess you could look at using the iterator to actually remove the item.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

static main(args) {   def list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
   Iterator i = list1.iterator();
   while (i.hasNext()) {
      n = i.next();
      if (n == 2) i.remove();
   }
   println(list1)
}​
```

but I don't see why you'd want to do it that way.

Comment: The example was really meant to only be an example of some real world situation. I ended up using the iterator to do the remove and it worked great. Thanks!