# Java/Grails - How to remove element from List without index

Tags: java, list, grails, groovy

I have a list

```
def list = []
def it = 1
list.add("+it+") // else we can add as string also
// or
list.add(it)
```

Above remove methods not removing element from list. How to remove element directly without index

```
list.remove("+it+")
// or
list.remove("1")  // where as 1 is element not index
```

How to remove directly without index. Dealing with 100K records if try to get via index will consume more time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046737/how-do-i-loop-through-a-list-and-remove-an-item-in-groovy

Comment: To remove all occurrences of a value in a list you can use `removeAll()` and to remove first occurrence, you can just use `remove()`.                                                                  `def list = ["1", "2", "4", "2", "4"]
def it = "4"
list.removeAll(it)
println ""+list​​​`      Output will be - [1, 2, 2]

Comment: @Amruta it will become hard code. when you do def it = '"4" consider variable number. and how will you add into list.

Comment: @SohamShetty I didn't get you?

Comment: @Amruta Thanks for your help I sorted that issue

Answer (score 1):

You can remove one or more items of a list doing this in groovy:

```
list -= ["1"]
```